# postgres PEM server, issue connecting the data base

Tags: postgresql

I'm not good with Postgres database troubleshooting, but I have a big project data base running on it.

Today suddenly I'm getting an error while I try to access my server, attached is the picture of the error screenshot. I really don't want to lose my data because its not backed up for few months.

I tried to reinstall but it says the port is messed up somewhere.

The message while I reinstall is:

> "psql:could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>  
>   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting 
>                           TCP/IP connection on port 5432?

Comment: Please see under "Related", at the right ------------------------>>>>

Comment: @wildplasser its not helping me. i tried many existing comments but not resolving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?` That are two questions you could answer:

- Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" (aka localhost) use:

  1. `ps auxw | grep postgres` # to answer this question
- ... accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? there are several ways to answer this question:

  2. `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 postgres`
  3. `telnet localhost 5432`
  4. `nmap -p 5432 localhost`

The result for (1) should be like:

```
postgres 30402  0.0  0.1 238488 12924 ?        S    12:09   0:01 /opt/postgres/bin/postmaster -D /data/db/postgres/pgdata
postgres 30409  0.0  0.0  94644  1308 ?        Ss   12:09   0:00 postgres: logger process                                
postgres 30411  0.0  0.3 238628 46964 ?        Ss   12:09   0:01 postgres: checkpointer process                          
postgres 30412  0.0  0.0 238628  4764 ?        Ss   12:09   0:00 postgres: writer process                                
postgres 30413  0.0  0.0 238628  5832 ?        Ss   12:09   0:00 postgres: wal writer process                            
postgres 30414  0.0  0.0 239036  2820 ?        Ss   12:09   0:01 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                   
postgres 30415  0.0  0.0  97884  2460 ?        Ss   12:09   0:03 postgres: stats collector process
```

---

The result for (2) should be like:

```
Password:
```

---

The result for (3) should be like:

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

---

The result for (4) should be like:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-05-18 15:14 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000050s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost.localdomain
PORT     STATE SERVICE
5432/tcp open  postgresql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
```

---

if (1) fails (gives no relevant output) postgres is obviously not running.

- you didn't start it (there should be a file for the service in /etc/init.d/)
- you attempted to start it, but it failed to startup

  - the binaries were not present, not found, or wrong
  - the data directory was not present, not found, or had the wrong owner/rights
  - the data directory contained files, but not for this version

if (2,3,4) fail (give no relevant output)

- postgres is not listening on the inet socket, but only on the `unix-domain` socket : check your config-file for `listen_address = '*'`
- finally, there could be a firewall-issue. (Check your iptables settings. or whatever)

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Hi @wildplasser, i tried your 3rd option in my windows machine , below is the error i got it. Im not sure what to do after this error. I also tried to backup the dumb files, i got the same error.                                                                                                                                                                 C:\Users\Babu>telnet localhost 5432
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5432: C
onnect failed

Comment: hey i got a fix and figured the postgresql is stopped due to some wrong admin settings happened (i dont know how this happens). I fixed it and i got back all the database. thanks for your time guys. im really happy this fixed. its my 6 months project work running on it.